# ChartJS no longer works in Lightning context

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, napili, chartjs

I have a few ChartJS charts displayed within lightning components.  Up until the other day they were working fine.  However, now when I try to draw the charts, the application crashes with no error message and the page simply becomes unresponsive.

I've validated that the charting library works fine in Visualforce, however when I try to load a lightning component in the Napili community (which I've beed doing successfully for over a year), it crashes.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?  When debugging, I can see all my debug logging statements from my JS controller & helper.  So the error is occurring when I actually create a new chart, like so:

```
 var myNewBarChart = new Chart(barCtx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barData,
    options: barOptions
 });
```

Edit: After testing, I've found that none of the following ChartJS libraries work as expected: 2.6, 2.5, 2.4, 2.2, 2.1.4 (last "known good version" of Chart.js for lightning).

I even set up a sample component on a single community page to test and get the same results/unresponsive page.

Here is the entirety of the code being used:

In the component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/jQuery" />
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/ChartJS214" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div style="max-width:300px;width:100%;margin:0 auto;">
        <canvas aura:id="InvestmentAllocationChart" 
            id="InvestmentAllocationChart" 
            class="InvestmentAllocationChart"></canvas>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

In the controller (this was taken almost entirely from [ChartJS docs](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v2.1.4/docs/07-Pie-Doughnut-Chart.md)):

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var data = {
            labels: [
                "Red",
                "Blue",
                "Yellow"
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [300, 50, 100],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "#FF6384",
                        "#36A2EB",
                        "#FFCE56"
                    ],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                        "#FF6384",
                        "#36A2EB",
                        "#FFCE56"
                    ]
                }]
        };
        var chart1 = $('#InvestmentAllocationChart');
        console.log('making the chart call');
        var ctx1 = new Chart(chart1, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: data
        });
    }
})
```

Again, no errors thrown, and I see my console logging statement just before making the call to create the chart.  When I check my Activity Monitor it shows that Chrome is taking up 100% of my CPU when I try to load this component.

Comment: what version of the library?

Comment: 2.6.0, I've also tested with 2.5.0 and 2.4.0

Comment: It may be because of locker service

Comment: The ["known good" with Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) version of ChartJS is 2.1.4. So worth trying that version.

Comment: @KeithC I just tested with 2.1.4 and having the same issue.  I stripped out anything custom and hard-coded an example from their site and still not working.

Comment: OK sorry the version downgrade didn't work. I suggest you remove the `aura:id="InvestmentAllocationChart"` from the canvas element as with locker turned on that will turn that element into a virtual DOM element and that may be the cause of the trouble. Otherwise I think you will have to use the JavaScript debugger to find out where the chart logic goes wrong and flag the problem with the authors.

Comment: @JasonBenkert : 2.1.4 seems to be working when bundle version is set to 38.0 and Chartjs version 2.3 seems work with noth 38.0 and 40.0 , try to clear you cache / kill chrome sessions and try the same.